# Github Enterprise Service Connection not available in Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, github-enterprise

I am trying to configure a Release Pipeline to use a repo hosted in a publicly exposed GitHub Enterprise instance but I am unable to access the Service Connection to the GitHub Enterprise repo.

I can setup a Service Connection to the Github Enterprise repo and verify the same but this connection is not available when adding an artifact to the Release Pipeline. I can add it to a Build Pipeline but not a Release Pipeline. In my case I need to deploy a Azure Resource using an ARM Template which is in the git repo and hence there is no "build" step involved and thus there is no need to create a Build Pipeline. I am using the "Azure Resource Group Deployment" task.

I have been able to setup and execute a Release Pipeline against a git repo hosted within the same Azure DevOps project very easily and expected to use the GitHub Enterprise hosted git repo just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

Release pipeline doesn't support GHE yet. As a workaround, you can create a Build Definition that can connect to GHE and produce and artifact. Release pipeline can consume the artifact from the build pipeline.